# Using agg() to calculate time interval between max time and min time

Tags: python, pandas

[image: df is here, plz click]

Hi I am new to Pandas, I am trying to get the time interval(max time - min time) by a MAC and the date

I am trying to use agg() but it will only return the max and min, do you guys know how I can just calculate the max - min?

The code I tried

```
df.groupby(['MAC','Date'])['Time'].agg('min','max')
```

only return max and mean and it is hard to calculate max - min because of format issues.

```
df.groupby(['MAC','Date'])['Time'].agg(np.max - np.min)
```

this didn't work

Comment: `s = df.groupby(['MAC','Date'])['Time'].agg(['min','max']); s['max']-s['min]`?

Comment: it will say it is series and need to change to str then datetime then it will say memory limit thing ,....

Comment: That means your `time` is actually string. Do `df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])` prior to the command above.

Comment: It works, thank you